# Is it possible to move an element that is flexed with position:absolute on hover?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I want my articles to jump up a few pixels but it seems to break the flex property. Is there any flex values or something that i can add or a better option? I can do it with float but I wonder whether it is possible with flex, and if so, how?.

```css
.article {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}

.article:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 4px 5px 4px black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#articleset1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="section">
  <div class="wrapper">



    <div id="articleset1">
      <article class="article">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem de ipsum de lisp Lorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem de ipsum de lisp Lorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem de ipsum de lisp</p>
      </article>

      <article class="article">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem Lorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem de ipsum de lispLorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem de ipsum de lisp de ipsum de lisp</p>
      </article>


      <article class="article">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem Lorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem de ipsum de lispLorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem de ipsum de lisp de ipsum de lisp</p>
      </article>

      <article class="article">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem Lorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem de ipsum de lispLorem ipsum dolero vicious lorem de ipsum de lisp de ipsum de lisp</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: don't use `position:absolute`, try using the `transform` property with `translate` instead. Something like `.article:hover { transform: translate(0,0); }`. There is also `translateX` and `translateY` if you just want to muniplate 1 coordinate

Comment: The hover effect with `position: absolute` doesn't "break the flex property"`. It simply removes the item from the document flow, and the siblings shift over to consume the empty space.

Comment: What exactly to you want to happen? Here's your code without absolute positioning. What's missing? https://jsfiddle.net/cqug7ohe/

Comment: Transform translate did the job. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

On hover use `transform`

```
.article:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 4px black;
    z-index: 111;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```